# Implementing a Type-erased list for fast write/read

Tags: c++, type-conversion, type-erasure

I am trying to implement a type erased data structure for writing and
reading large arrays of any type in a list, with the following
requirements:

- Fast insert of bulk data (receive a `std::vector<T>`, where T is a primitive type).
- Fast read of all/latest values if types match
- Read/convert if types mismatch. In most cases from primitive to primitive (e.g double->float, int->double)

The interface I was thinking of would look something like this:

```
class Trace {
      template<typename T> std::vector<T> read();
      template<typename T> std::vector<T> latest();
      template<typename T> void append(std::vector<T> values);
      template<typename T> void replace(std::vector<T> values);
      void clear();
};
```

Which is then used in a TraceHandler class (Singleton structure), which allows access to traces per key:

```
class TraceHandler {
public:
  template<typename T>
  std::vector<T> read(std::string const& key);
  template<typename T>
  void write(std::string const& key, std::vector<T> const& val);
private:
  // STore all Traces for different types
};
```

And a useage would look something like this:

```
TraceHandler th;
std::vector<double> vals(1000,1.0), res;
th.write("values",vals);
std::vector<int> resInt;
res = th.read<double>("values");
resInt = th.read<int>("values");
```

Our current implementation creates a Trace for each datatype and the
user has to keep track of the correct type, which is not very
flexible (e.g write using `writeDouble()`, read using `readDouble`).

My first approach was to change the type of the internal storage
vector to an `any` type (we are using Poco libraries, so I was using
`Poco::Any` and `Poco::DynamicAny`), but this leads to a big
performance hit.

Data is written from Devices with high frequencies (data is acquired
with up to 20khz, then written in blocks of around 4k to the Trace),
and the measured performance difference between a plain vector and one
of an Any type was of factor 500-1000 (measured 800ms vs. 4ms for big
bulk insert/read in a loop). Most of the time gets lost due to
constructor calls vs simple memcopy.

So my question is: Is there a way to implement this interface (or an
alternative) with good bulk insert/read performance?

---

Edit:
This is the current implementation I'm using:

```
class LWDynamicVector
{
private:
  typedef std::vector<Poco::DynamicAny> DataList;   
  DataList m_data;
public:
  LWDynamicVector() {}

  template<typename T> std::vector<T> read() {
    return std::vector<T>(m_data.begin(),m_data.end());
  }

  template<typename T> void writeAppend(std::vector<T> v) {
    m_data.insert(m_data.end(),v.begin(),v.end());
    }

  template<typename T> void writeReplace(std::vector<T> v) {
    m_data.assign(v.begin(),v.end());
  }
};
```

And the Test I am using:

```
TEST(DynamicVector,Performance) {
  typedef double Type;
  size_t runs = 100; size_t N = 20480;
  std::vector<Type> input;
  input.reserve(N);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    input.push_back(rand());
  }

  {
    OldVector<Type> instance;
    Poco::Timestamp ts;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < runs; ++i) {
      instance.writeAppend(input);
    }
    std::cout << "Old vector: time elapsed(ms) = " << ts.elapsed() / 1000.0 << std::endl; 
    std::vector<Type> output = instance.read();
    EXPECT_EQ(output.back(),output.back()); 
  }
  {
    LWDynamicVector dbv;
    Poco::Timestamp ts;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < runs; ++i) {
      dbv.writeAppend(input);
    }
    std::cout << "New vector: time elapsed(ms) = " << ts.elapsed() / 1000.0 << std::endl;

    std::vector<Type> output = dbv.read<Type>();
    EXPECT_EQ(output.back(),output.back());
  }

}
```

Which results in:

```
Old vector: time elapsed(ms) = 44.004
New vector: time elapsed(ms) = 4380.44
```

Regarding compiler options and optimizations: Unfortunately I'm stuck at the current settings without the option to change them. In most scenarios the build runs in debug mode, but still has to meet the timing requirements. But anyways, the performance does not improve in release mode:

```
Old vector: time elapsed(ms) = 20.002
New vector: time elapsed(ms) = 1013.1
```

Comment: how does OldVector look like? did the old one also convert the types? Are you using C++11?

Comment: @Surt At the moment `OldVector` can only store one type. Essencially it is a `std::vector<T>` with locks and a new interface. We are not using C++11 at the moment, but I would be interested in any solution which uses C++11 as well.

Comment: Is the data written the same type for the same run, for example no combination of double and int in the same measurement? no repeat of for example 7 doubles followed by 10 ints and 3 strings in the same trace?

Comment: @Surt yes. One can assume that any `write` is always called with the same type. A `read` can be done for different types.

Comment: And you don't want to have your users to define their data types 'Trace<TestDataType> test;' for ex. 'Trace<double> test;'?

Comment: Is this a correct interpretation of what you want '

    Trace<double> trace;

    std::vector<double> data;
    data = measure();
    trace.append(data);

    std::vector<float> eval;  // other type than trace
    eval = trace.read();'

Comment: @Surt Access should not be done directly, but over a TraceHandler structure. I added an example in the question. I was experimenting with your suggested structure already, but it resulted in a problem of storing the different traces within a class.

Comment: Does each individual Trace instance need to contain a mixture of types, or just a single type per instance?

Comment: @Useless it is always one type per instance

Comment: OK, so you can erase type per-container, rather than per-element. That should be more efficient, but you might need to write a nifty polymorphic coercing iterator. It might be a while before I have time to write up an answer, though.

Comment: It looks like for any given vector you are always reading or writing a single type. Is that correct?

Comment: @b4hand No, this is not the case. The whole point is to be able to read/write any type without the need to know the internally stored type. The only assumption is that a vector will be filled mostly with the same type.

Comment: Then the given interface for Trace and TraceHandler is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you are writing only primitive types. You know all these types in advance. Use a plain old union + type tag. Can't beat that. `boost::variant` should also work.

```
typedef enum { type_int, type_double } type_tag_t;
struct data_t {
  type_tag_t tag;
  union {
     int int_elem;
     double double_elem;
  }
};
```

`boost::variant` should also work.

Alternatively, store entire `std::vector`fuls of data in a

```
std::map<std::string, 
          boost::variant<std::vector<int>, 
                         std::vector<double>, 
                         ...
                        >
        > mymap;
```

Comment: You are talking about an internal `std::vector<Union>`, right? I like the idea, and certainly have to try it out. But I guess reading will be slow, even if both types match, as you'd have to copy from your internal vector to a result vector element by element.

Comment: It will most certainly be faster than `std::vector<whatever::any>`.

Comment: The second version is what I was using in the end (just with an any class instead of boost::variant, as it makes no difference). I was hoping to avoid having to duplicate code for each supported type, but as it seems this is not possible. At least I can have type selection only on few selected places.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that the problem is in the gather data phase and not in the evaluation.

First point is that your `OldVector` didn't need to make any type conversions, therefore on POD data it would essentially use a memcpy on the data when it inserted.

DynamicAny is a very nice class if you really really need dynamic variable content, but deep within the class we can see (one of) the problem for performance

```
VarHolder* _pHolder;
```

which means some memory allocation for each data inserted and some house keeping.

Now an *concept* implementation as I can't test it, your Trace class

```
template<class T>
class Trace {
    std::vector<T> trace;

public:
    template<typename T, class U> std::vector<U> read();
    template<typename T, class U> std::vector<T> latest();
    template<typename T> void append(std::vector<T> values);
    template<typename T> void replace(std::vector<T> values);
    void clear();
};
```

That would work fine if you only used one T. Hide the types in TraceHandler

```
class TraceHandler {
public:
  template<typename T, class U>
  std::vector<U> read(std::string const& key);
  template<typename T>
  void write(std::string const& key, std::vector<T> const& val);
private:
  // Store all Traces for different types
  std::unordered_map<const std::string, Poco::DynamicAny> values;  // abstraction
};
```

This only works if each key only used one T and DynamicAny can take a vector.

```
template<class T>
void TraceHandler::write(std::string const& key, std::vector<T> const& val) {
  if (values.find(key) == values.end()) {  // doesn't exists
    Trace<T> temp;
    temp.append(val);
    values[key] = temp;
  } else
    values[key].append(val);  // only works if DynamicAny can return original type
}
```

Will it work with your use case?

```
TraceHandler th;
std::vector<double> vals(1000,1.0), res;
th.write("values",vals);
std::vector<int> resInt;
//res = th.read("values"); // could work if DynamicAny could return original.
td.read("values", res);
//resInt = th.read("values"); // wont work as read can't guess the type
th.read("values", resInt); // read can guess the return type

// handle conversion from stored type to wanted return type
template<class T, class U>
void TraceHandler::read(std::string const& key, std::vector<U>& res) {
  // convert from T to U, maybe use Poco???
  ... work here!!! can be slow as its after it is captured
}

// specialization where T==U ... more work needed.
template<class T, class U>
std::vector<T>& TraceHandler::read(std::string const& key, std::vector<T>& res) {
  // no conversion needed
  // convince DynamicAny to return the original data
  res = values[key]; // will not work out of the box???
}
```

This should have better performance as there is only one use of Poco::DynamicAny per table per call. Some further optimizations could be made to lessen copying but that can be done later after it runs at all.

Comment: I tried to store my Traces in DynamicAny holders. The problem is that you lose the information on which type is stored. If you call `TraceHandler::read` and try to convert from T to U, you don't have the information anymore on which type T is, so you cannot convert it.

Comment: @MatthiasB, Looking a bit further if the original was std::vector<double> then values[key].extract<std::vector<double>> should return a const ref to the original?

Comment: A copy would be better. The non-reduced version has functions where not the whole vector is returned, but a reduced version (e.g only the data since the last write).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<boost::any>
```

it's a library dedicated to a type that implements type erasure techniques .

[*boost::any*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: I just tried this, and unfortunately this still has the same performance hits as `Poco::Any` or `Poco::DynamicAny`. In my testcase the boost::any implementation takes around 20s, while the direct implementation has around 20ms to 150ms (depending on the typed used, char to double). This was read/write of the same type, so no conversion is happening.

Comment: @MatthiasB did you tried compiling it with different options ? if you are using msvc try Release mode. What is your platform and compiler of reference ?

Comment: The problem is this should run on different platforms (down to older computers in the Core2Duo range, all running VisualStudio2008) in debug mode. I tested a release build for reference, which got the difference down to a factor of 30 for relevant cases, which is still kindof slow.